# ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'1.0.0.7' (using password: YES) mysql in kubernetes

Tags: mysql, docker, kubernetes

I am running MySQL 8 on Kubernetes by using deployment, service and secret files which are given below. but getting access denied error. I tried all the StackOverflow solutions but did not work for me.

Note:- I am using service type as load balancer which is having external IP.

Please help me to solve this issue, if anyone has a solution context

My Kubernetes files are:-

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mysql
  namespace: mysql
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 3306
  selector:
    app: mysql
  type: LoadBalancer
---
apiVersion: apps/v1 # for versions before 1.9.0 use apps/v1beta2
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mysql
  namespace: mysql
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mysql
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mysql
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: mysql:8.0
        name: mysql
        env:
          # Use secret in real usage
        - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: mysql-pass
              key: password
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3306
          name: mysql
        volumeMounts:
        - name: mysql-persistent-storage
          mountPath: /var/lib/mysql
      volumes:
      - name: mysql-persistent-storage
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: mysql-pv-claim
```

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: mysql-pass
  namespace: mysql
type: kubernetes.io/basic-auth
stringData:
  password: cGFzc3dvcmQK
```

output:-

```
mysql -u root -ppassword -P 3306 -h 1.2.3.4
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'1.0.0.7' (using password: YES)
```

Comment: Either your user name or your password is incorrect. not really sure this is a programming problem.

Comment: I tried username as root and password is password in my case

Comment: Luckily you tried the username and password that you think you should use, but @Shadow stated: "Either your user name or your password is incorrect!"

Comment: As per me username and password both are correct , that you can check in my given yamls. not sure what’s wrong...

Comment: Unfortunately, it is what mysql considers to be the good username and password that counts.

Comment: @Shadow didn’t get you

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql -u root -pcGFzc3dvcmQK  -P 3306 -h 1.2.3.4
```

use your secret passowrd please

Comment: Tried as per suggestion but it's not working

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).